# Getting filtered/aggregated data from Tableau Server via REST API from custom page

Tags: rest, api, tableau-api

I have existing Tableu Server workbook with diagrams and own datasources(mysql).

Is it possible to *fetch* data from Tableau Server via Rest Api, e.g. if I build a custom web dashboard and need only data from Tableau?

I am interested in Tableaus ability to *filter/aggregate data*, thats what it does for its diagrams, would be great to harvest it from custom Python web page for my custom diagrams (e.g. for D3 or Highcharts).

Is "Extracts API" the right direction for this?
Or the path with ["Query View Data"](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref.htm#query_view_data) is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specify the filter values and get the exact set of data that your diagrams/workbooks are using, go with the Query View Data solution.

If you pull the data from the extract, you will get it exactly as it is out of the extract. This means if you have filters or aggregation done in your visualization (which is processed *after* the extract), it won't apply to the extracted data.